# top down ranges merge?

Tags: algorithm, merge, range

I want to merge some intervals like this:

```
>>> ranges = [(30, 45), (40, 50), (10, 50), (60, 90), (90, 100)]
>>> merge(ranges)
[(10, 50), (60, 100)]
```

I'm not in cs field. I know how to do it by iteration, but wonder if there's a more efficient "top-down" approach to merge them more efficiently, maybe using some special data structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the efficient way to do it is to use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Hi Jason, I just looked up interval tree, and got the basic idea. But I'm confused about how to use that to merge intervals, could you give me a brief description of the missing link here? Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to construct the interval tree, and then sort the intervals and use the leftmost interval as first query, search for the tree and get all intersecting intervals, then merge those, and do this iteratively until the merged range doesn't change; and then use the next right interval to start the second round of the scan. Is this the correct way to scan the whole tree for all the "subtrees" of overlapping intervals?

Answer (score 3):

Interval tree definitely works, but it is more complex than what you need. Interval tree is an "online" solution, and so it allows you to add some intervals, look at the union, add more intervals, look again, etc.

If you have all the intervals upfront, you can do something simpler:

1. Start with the input

   ranges = [(30, 45), (40, 50), (10, 50)]
2. Convert the range list into a list of endpoints. If you have range (A, B), you'll convert it to two endpoints: (A, 0) will be the left endpoint and (B, 1) wil be the right endpoint.

   endpoints = [(30, 0), (45, 1), (40, 0), (50, 1), (10, 0), (50, 1)]
3. Sort the endpoints

   endpoints = [(10, 0), (30, 0), (40, 0), (45, 1), (50, 1), (50, 1)]
4. Scan forward through the endpoints list. Increment a counter when you see a left endpoint and decrement the counter when you see a right endpoint. Whenever the counter hits 0, you close the current merged interval.

This solution can be implemented in a few lines.

Comment: would this work if there are more than one cluster of overlapping intervals?

Comment: I really like the elegant idea though :)

Comment: Yes, it works no matter how many clusters there are. Each time the counter reaches zero, you reached the end of a merged cluster. The next endpoint must be a left endpoint (or else your data got messed up), and it will start the next merged cluster.

Comment: I see it now, even though I think this should have similar time complexity as the sort and pairwise merge approach, right?

Comment: True - you can sort the intervals based on the left endpoint and then iterate forwards, merging intervals if they overlap. Honestly, I didn't think of that approach :)

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm in **C#** does what you want. It uses `DateTime` interval ranges, but you can adapt it however you like. Once the collection is sorted in ascending start order, if the start of the next interval is at or before the end of the previous one, they overlap, and you extend the end time outward if needed. Otherwise they don't overlap, and you save the prior one off to the results.

```
public static List<DateTimeRange> MergeTimeRanges(List<DateTimeRange> inputRanges)
{
  List<DateTimeRange> mergedRanges = new List<DateTimeRange>();

  // Sort in ascending start order.
  inputRanges.Sort();

  DateTime currentStart = inputRanges[0].Start;
  DateTime currentEnd = inputRanges[0].End;

  for (int i = 1; i < inputRanges.Count; i++)
  {
    if (inputRanges[i].Start <= currentEnd)
    {
      if (inputRanges[i].End > currentEnd)
      {
        currentEnd = inputRanges[i].End; // Extend range.
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // Save current range to output.
      mergedRanges.Add(new DateTimeRange(currentStart, currentEnd));

      currentStart = inputRanges[i].Start;
      currentEnd = inputRanges[i].End;
    }
  }

  mergedRanges.Add(new DateTimeRange(currentStart, currentEnd));

  return mergedRanges;
}
```